# Searching in a complex json information in an tinyDB

Tags: python, json, tinydb

I've the following json information in a tinyDB

```
{
"_default": {
    "1": {
        "status": {
            "timestamp": "2021-03-21T15:12:04.025Z",
            "total_count": 4436
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "def"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "qwe"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I understand how to search in the status section i.e.

```
listings = db.table('_default')
E = Query()
print(listings.search(E.status.total_count == 4436))
```

But how can I search inside the data section with [] ?

Answer (score 0):

You could load it as a string and parse it by index, since data is a list.  So just change `[0]` with whatever index you are interested in seeing in the data piece

```
import json

x = """{
   "_default":{
      "1":{
         "status":{
            "timestamp":"2021-03-21T15:12:04.025Z",
            "total_count":4436
         },
         "data":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"abc"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"def"
            },
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"qwe"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}"""

y = json.loads(x)


print(y["_default"]["1"]["data"][0])
```

results in:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'abc'}
```

EDIT: I see you are working with DB tables for this, so you it wouldn't apply exactly but you can get the parsing by index idea at least